# Expect script not matching output

Tags: expect

At my wits end:

Need expect to match the following string, which is also colour coded. Quotes are the illustrate the blank space to the right.

```
"FuseMQ:karaf@root> "
```

Using just "root" sends before the > prompt is ready, in some cases, not all.

```
expect "root" {

0m:\u001b[36mkaraf\u001b[0m\u001b[1m@\u001b[0m\u001b[34mroot"
send: sending "osgi:install wrap:file:/apps/fuse/fuse-mq-7.1.0.fuse-047/ 
lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar\r" to { exp4 }
```

I cannot find a regexp that works. The output from expect -d is as follows when it works

```
u001b[0m\u001b[1m@\u001b[0m\u001b[34mroot\u001b[0m> " (spawn_id
 exp4) match glob pattern "root"? yes
```

But I cannot figure out how to match this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `expect "root\\u001b\[0m> $"`

Comment: I get the old error about brackets... Escaping the bracket worked however. I now have `expect -re "root\\u001b\\\[0m> $"`  Additionally I found that send "\r\r" in between each expect clause made it work a whole lot better. Blame the fusemq shell. Thanks. Will accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this, where you have the strings you want to match, and allow for "stuff" in between.

```
set prompt {FuseMQ.*:.*karaf.*@.*root.*> $}
expect -re $prompt
```